# GaussianDropout vs. Dropout vs. GaussianNoise in Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, gaussian, dropout

Can anyone explain the difference between the different dropout styles? From the [documentation](https://tensorflow.google.cn/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/GaussianDropout), I assumed that instead of dropping some units to zero (dropout), GaussianDropout multiplies those units by some distribution. However, when testing in practice, all units are touched. The result looks more like the classic GaussianNoise.

```
tf.random.set_seed(0)
layer = tf.keras.layers.GaussianDropout(.05, input_shape=(2,))
data = np.arange(10).reshape(5, 2).astype(np.float32)
print(data)

outputs = layer(data, training=True)
print(outputs)
```

results:

```
[[0. 1.]
 [2. 3.]
 [4. 5.]
 [6. 7.]
 [8. 9.]]
tf.Tensor(
[[0.    1.399]
 [1.771 2.533]
 [4.759 3.973]
 [5.562 5.94 ]
 [8.882 9.891]], shape=(5, 2), dtype=float32)
```

edit:

Apparently, this is what I wanted all along:

```
def RealGaussianDropout(x, rate, stddev):

    keep_prob = 1 - rate
    random_tensor = tf.random.uniform(tf.shape(x))
    keep_mask = tf.cast(random_tensor >= rate, tf.float32)   
    noised = x + K.random_normal(tf.shape(x), mean=.0, stddev=stddev)   
    ret = tf.multiply(x, keep_mask) + tf.multiply(noised, (1-keep_mask))

    return ret


outputs = RealGaussianDropout(data,0.2,0.1)
print(outputs)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are right... GaussianDropout and GaussianNoise are very similar. you can test all the similarities by reproducing them on your own

```
def dropout(x, rate):

    keep_prob = 1 - rate
    scale = 1 / keep_prob
    ret = tf.multiply(x, scale)
    random_tensor = tf.random.uniform(tf.shape(x))
    keep_mask = random_tensor >= rate
    ret = tf.multiply(ret, tf.cast(keep_mask, tf.float32))
    
    return ret

def gaussian_dropout(x, rate):
    
    stddev = np.sqrt(rate / (1.0 - rate))
    ret = x * K.random_normal(tf.shape(x), mean=1.0, stddev=stddev)
    
    return ret

def gaussian_noise(x, stddev):
    
    ret = x + K.random_normal(tf.shape(x), mean=.0, stddev=stddev)
    
    return ret
```

Gaussian noise simply adds random normal values with 0 mean while gaussian dropout simply multiplies random normal values with 1 mean. These operations involve all the elements of the input. The classic dropout turn to 0 some input elements operating a scaling on the others

**DROPOUT**

```
data = np.arange(10).reshape(5, 2).astype(np.float32)

set_seed(0)
layer = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(.4)
out1 = layer(data, training=True)
set_seed(0)
out2 = dropout(data, .4)
print(tf.reduce_all(out1 == out2).numpy()) # TRUE
```

**GAUSSIANDROPOUT**

```
data = np.arange(10).reshape(5, 2).astype(np.float32)

set_seed(0)
layer = tf.keras.layers.GaussianDropout(.05)
out1 = layer(data, training=True)
set_seed(0)
out2 = gaussian_dropout(data, .05)
print(tf.reduce_all(out1 == out2).numpy()) # TRUE
```

**GAUSSIANNOISE**

```
data = np.arange(10).reshape(5, 2).astype(np.float32)

set_seed(0)
layer = tf.keras.layers.GaussianNoise(.3)
out1 = layer(data, training=True)
set_seed(0)
out2 = gaussian_noise(data, .3)
print(tf.reduce_all(out1 == out2).numpy()) # TRUE
```

to grant reproducibility we used (TF2):

```
def set_seed(seed):
    
    tf.random.set_seed(seed)
    os.environ['PYTHONHASHSEED'] = str(seed)
    np.random.seed(seed)
    random.seed(seed)
```

Comment: thank you for the detailed answer. It's strange that they made the effort to define two such similar functions. I'm still interested in a layer that works like dropout and randomly distributes noise to, say, 20% of the data. Has no one tried this yet?

Comment: yes, I don't know why precisely... however you can build your own dropout function/layer mixing the masking ability of the classic dropout with tho noise addition of the gaussian method if u retain it valuable